# React Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:48)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Can someone help me? I just create react app then I start it immediately. Then I got an error something like this. I don't know much about webpack.

**CMD**

```
./src/index.js 1:48
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:48)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/LENOVO/Mine/project-new/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
|
```

I just type `npx create-react-app ./` in the directory then `npm start` then this error happened.
I have tried to make 3 react app and same thing happened and i never touch the webpack before.

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**This is my webpack.config.js**
https://pastebin.com/NVHdYGGN

**@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js**

```
// This is a patch for mozilla/source-map#349 -
// internally, it uses the existence of the `fetch` global to toggle browser behaviours.
// That check, however, will break when `fetch` polyfills are used for SSR setups.
// We "reset" the polyfill here to ensure it won't interfere with source-map generation.
const originalFetch = global.fetch;
delete global.fetch;

const { SourceMapConsumer, SourceMapGenerator, SourceNode } = require('source-map');
const { Template } = require('webpack');

/**
 * Generates an identity source map from a source file.
 * @param {string} source The content of the source file.
 * @param {string} resourcePath The name of the source file.
 * @returns {import('source-map').RawSourceMap} The identity source map.
 */
function getIdentitySourceMap(source, resourcePath) {
  const sourceMap = new SourceMapGenerator();
  sourceMap.setSourceContent(resourcePath, source);

  source.split('\n').forEach((line, index) => {
    sourceMap.addMapping({
      source: resourcePath,
      original: {
        line: index + 1,
        column: 0,
      },
      generated: {
        line: index + 1,
        column: 0,
      },
    });
  });

  return sourceMap.toJSON();
}

/**
 * Gets a runtime template from provided function.
 * @param {function(): void} fn A function containing the runtime template.
 * @returns {string} The "sanitized" runtime template.
 */
function getTemplate(fn) {
  return Template.getFunctionContent(fn).trim().replace(/^ {2}/gm, '');
}

const RefreshSetupRuntime = getTemplate(require('./RefreshSetup.runtime')).replace(
  '$RefreshRuntimePath$',
  require.resolve('react-refresh/runtime').replace(/\\/g, '/')
);
const RefreshModuleRuntime = getTemplate(require('./RefreshModule.runtime'));

/**
 * A simple Webpack loader to inject react-refresh HMR code into modules.
 *
 * [Reference for Loader API](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/)
 * @this {import('webpack').loader.LoaderContext}
 * @param {string} source The original module source code.
 * @param {import('source-map').RawSourceMap} [inputSourceMap] The source map of the module.
 * @param {*} [meta] The loader metadata passed in.
 * @returns {void}
 */
function ReactRefreshLoader(source, inputSourceMap, meta) {
  const callback = this.async();

  /**
   * @this {import('webpack').loader.LoaderContext}
   * @param {string} source
   * @param {import('source-map').RawSourceMap} [inputSourceMap]
   * @returns {Promise<[string, import('source-map').RawSourceMap]>}
   */
  async function _loader(source, inputSourceMap) {
    if (this.sourceMap) {
      let originalSourceMap = inputSourceMap;
      if (!originalSourceMap) {
        originalSourceMap = getIdentitySourceMap(source, this.resourcePath);
      }

      const node = SourceNode.fromStringWithSourceMap(
        source,
        await new SourceMapConsumer(originalSourceMap)
      );

      node.prepend([RefreshSetupRuntime, '\n\n']);
      node.add(['\n\n', RefreshModuleRuntime]);

      const { code, map } = node.toStringWithSourceMap();
      return [code, map.toJSON()];
    } else {
      return [[RefreshSetupRuntime, source, RefreshModuleRuntime].join('\n\n'), inputSourceMap];
    }
  }

  _loader.call(this, source, inputSourceMap).then(
    ([code, map]) => {
      callback(null, code, map, meta);
    },
    (error) => {
      callback(error);
    }
  );
}

module.exports = ReactRefreshLoader;

// Restore the original value of the `fetch` global, if it exists
if (originalFetch) {
  global.fetch = originalFetch;
}
```

**babel-loader/lib/index.js**
https://pastebin.com/sXm9sz0n

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you created your react app? Could you show the steps that you did ?

Comment: I just did npx create-react-app then just started it

Comment: Could you provide a minimal eeproducible example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sure, sorry idk much about the webpack

Answer (score 12, accepted):

+There seems to be an issue with the new release `4.0.2` of `create-react-app` [[Reference]](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10518).
You can use the previous, `4.0.1`, by doing the following.

1. Edit `package.json` and change the `"react-scripts"` value to `"4.0.1"`.
2. Run `npm install`.
3. Run `npm start`.

Comment: Had same problem with version 4.0.1

Comment: Solved my problem

Comment: @LeandroCotti check my answer below. I had an issue with my PC's name which contained a single quote in it.  If you're using Windows and you have single quote in your PC's name, try to move project folder outside that path (put it under C:/Users/ and set permissions for that folder to 'Full Control' for 'Everyone'. Let me know if that's the case.

Comment: Works for me too!!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had a single quote character `'` in my PC's name (e.g. `dummy'sPC`) which caused react-scripts package to crash in version **4.0.2** and **4.0.3** (but not in 4.0.1 which was interesting to me).

After moving project to a higher level folder (e.g. `C:/Users/my-app`) and installing node modules everything was working properly.

At the end I can use `react-scripts v4.0.3` but only when project's path doesn't contain `dummy'sPC` string in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Luka . I wonder how you figured it out. I had also had  a ' in my project directory. I was struggling with this error for around 10 minutes.

Comment: You're welcome @DamanArora . I got an idea from https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10518#issuecomment-855382927 I even posted the same response there.

Comment: Thank you so  much!

Comment: You are a lifesaver.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and what I did was like mentioned in the above comment, I changed the "react-scripts" value in package.json to 4.0.1 and ran **npm install** again. Then **npm start**
and it worked pretty well. Did you use the same method or what method you followed in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple
just check all the folder's names in the file path.
if any folder has ' symbol like "rifat's folder" , remove the 's
and it will work
it's basically a rename issue