# I am unable to run react app using npm start command

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, create-react-app, npm-start

when I create react app using `npx create-react-app app-name` the app gets created but when I start the app using `npm start` i get the following error, please can someone guide me

Failed to compile.

./src/index.js 1:39
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:39)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('D:/Project's/React/CRUD-Operations/client/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
> | $RefreshSetup$(module.id);

Comment: Please can someone help me I'm unable to find anything online

Comment: This might be because of [latest release](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10518) of `create-react-app`. Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66255262/) help?